# Eclipselink aggregate and constructor issue

Tags: eclipselink, aggregate, jpql

I am using Eclipselink 2.2.1.v20110722-r9776

I have the following query:

```
TypedQuery<FundMasterDTO> secQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT new com.dto.FundMasterDTO("+" sum(appAmount), sum(redemptionPrice) from security", FundMasterDTO.class);
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT new com.dto.FundMasterDTO( sum(app_amount), sum(redemption_price) from security], line 1, column 80: syntax error at [from].

Internal Exception: MissingTokenException(inserted [@-1,0:0='<missing RIGHT_ROUND_BRACKET>',<84>,1:80] at from); nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager:
```

If i dont use the aggregate function, SUM, then all works well. If i remove the constructor then i get a list back.

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, you're missing a right round bracket:

```
SELECT new com.dto.FundMasterDTO( sum(app_amount), sum(redemption_price)) ...
                                                two parentheses here ---^
```